# How can you specify a source address in a multicast join in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, networking, multicast

In the network-multicast Haskell documentation, I see a function

```
setInterface :: Socket -> HostName -> IO ()
Set the outgoing interface address of the multicast.
```

How can I use this to specify a source-address in a multicast join? The following code, when ran, produces the given output.. (IP Addresses masked for privacy)

## Code

```
import Network.BSD
import Network.Socket hiding (send, sendTo, recv, recvFrom)
import Network.Socket.ByteString
import Network.Multicast hiding (multicastReceiver)
import Text.Printf
import Data.ByteString as B hiding (putStrLn)

sourceIP = "192.168.MMM.NNN"
mcastIP = "224.0.XXX.YYY"
mcastPort = 32101

mcastLoop :: Socket -> IO ()
mcastLoop sock = do
    (msg, addr) <- recvFrom sock 1024
    printf "%s-> %s\n" (show addr) (show . B.unpack $ msg)
    mcastLoop sock 

multicastReceiver :: HostName -> PortNumber -> IO Socket
multicastReceiver host port = do
    proto <- getProtocolNumber "udp"
    sock  <- socket AF_INET Datagram proto
    setInterface sock sourceIP

{-# LINE 81 "src/Network/Multicast.hsc" #-}
    setInterface sock sourceIP
    bindSocket sock $ SockAddrInet port 0
    setInterface sock sourceIP
{-# LINE 82 "src/Network/Multicast.hsc" #-}
    setInterface sock sourceIP
    addMembership sock host
    return sock

main :: IO ()
main = withSocketsDo $ do
    sock <- multicastReceiver mcastIP mcastPort
    dropMembership sock mcastIP
    setInterface sock sourceIP
    addMembership sock mcastIP
    mcastLoop sock
```

## Output

```
~ - sudo tcpdump -n -nn -i any "host 224.0.XXX.YYY"
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 65535 bytes
08:00:44.463153 IP 10.52.ZZZ.WWW > 224.0.XXX.YYY: igmp v2 report 224.0.XXX.YYY
08:00:52.498722 IP 10.52.ZZZ.WWW > 224.0.XXX.YYY: igmp v2 report 224.0.XXX.YYY
08:00:58.301711 IP 10.52.ZZZ.WWW > 224.0.XXX.YYY: igmp v2 report 224.0.XXX.YYY
08:01:08.408710 IP 10.52.ZZZ.WWW > 224.0.XXX.YYY: igmp v2 report 224.0.XXX.YYY
08:02:04.104707 IP 10.52.ZZZ.WWW > 224.0.XXX.YYY: igmp v2 report 224.0.XXX.YYY
08:03:08.545718 IP 10.52.ZZZ.WWW > 224.0.XXX.YYY: igmp v2 report 224.0.XXX.YYY
08:04:02.634709 IP 10.52.ZZZ.WWW > 224.0.XXX.YYY: igmp v2 report 224.0.XXX.YYY
08:05:03.757718 IP 10.52.ZZZ.WWW > 224.0.XXX.YYY: igmp v2 report 224.0.XXX.YYY
08:06:10.600716 IP 10.52.ZZZ.WWW > 224.0.XXX.YYY: igmp v2 report 224.0.XXX.YYY
08:07:07.248707 IP 10.52.ZZZ.WWW > 224.0.XXX.YYY: igmp v2 report 224.0.XXX.YYY
08:08:10.202708 IP 10.52.ZZZ.WWW > 224.0.XXX.YYY: igmp v2 report 224.0.XXX.YYY
08:09:02.390708 IP 10.52.ZZZ.WWW > 224.0.XXX.YYY: igmp v2 report 224.0.XXX.YYY
```

This is the comparison of C++/Haskell applications running (as requested by EJP)

```
~/sandbox - sudo tcpdump -i any "host 192.168.MMM.NNN"        
[sudo] password for gresko: 
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 65535 bytes

# C++ application started
16:15:55.490156 IP 192.168.MMM.NNN > 224.0.62.108: igmp v2 report 224.0.62.108
# C++ application killed
16:16:04.689342 IP 192.168.MMM.NNN > all-routers.mcast.net: igmp leave 224.0.62.108

# Haskell application started
# Haskell application killed
```

Comment: This question is similar, but does not answer my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111204/how-to-specify-a-local-bond-interface-to-multicast-socket-in-haskell

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't work"?  What behavior do you expect versus what you're seeing?

Comment: Elaborated the expected behavior

Comment: You need to call setInterface *before* joining the group. How this is done in Haskell is another question. Maybe dropMembership/addInterface/addMembership. Looks like they have misdesigned their constructor to me.

Comment: @EJP: that's what I figured. I also tried copying the source of multicastReceiver and inserting the setInterface call right after the socket is created. That didn't work either..

Comment: That should work. Are you sure you ran that modified code?

Comment: See the updated description for the code I ran.

Comment: Try the setInterface after the bind and before the addMembership.

Comment: That doesn't work. I also tried interspersing the `setInterface` in between every line after the socket is created.

Comment: This all suggests that their `setInterface` method doesn't work at all. Does their `addMembership` method have an overload with an interface address in it?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's no alternative version of `setInterface`.

Comment: OK Can we now define 'doesn't work'? You definitely see no IGMP message going out that interface when you join?

Comment: If I don't specify an interface, the IGMP message goes out with a default source IP, call it A. After setting `setInterface` with an argument of an IP, call it B, I still see A being the source address. If I run an equivalent C++ application, it can send a join with source address B, without issue. (All confirmed with tcpdump). The requested data only comes in when sending a join with source B.

Answer (score 1):

The Haskell authors haven't allowed for this in their constructor. It shouldn't take a group parameter at all, as it doesn't allow you to set the multicast interface before joining the group. Or, the group should be optional.

Also I would say that they should provide an `addMembership()` override or alternative that takes an NIC address as well as a group address. The underlying Sockets system call supports it after all.

*However,* unless Haskell's `setInterface()` method doesn't work at all, in which case there isn't much you can do, the sequence of

```
dropMembership()
setInterface()
addMembership()
```

should work.

I would want to confirm that you genuinely don't see any IGMP messages going out that interface before I concluded that `setInterface()` doesn't work.

I suspect that what is really happening is that the sender isn't sending properly.

Comment: Good idea. I've combined the culmination of tips into one code/output sample in the original post. Take a look and let me know what you think. EDIT: Note, it's interesting, because setting an invalid source ip (aka an IP not possessed by any interface in the computer) in `setInterface` yields an error. So it seems as though it is actually doing *something*.

Comment: `-i any` means sniff on all interfaces, `"host x.y.z.w"` means capture traffic to/from the specified host. The equivalent capture from C++ shows that the outbound packets have the "192.168.MMM.NNN" as their source IP. Further, if a "membership report" isn't a join, what is?